# High Volume Geocoding API?

Tags: geocoding

I would like some recommendations on a high volume Geocoding API.  I've reached out to Google and Yahoo so far.  Google wants too much money for too little offering and Yahoo doesn't have a commercial offering.

I need to geocode about 250,000 items per day initially, but this number will grow exponentially in the near future, so I need a solution that will grow with us.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Previously, I retrieved too many geo look up; as the result, google blocked my ip. Finally, I end up storing both lat and log in database once looked up.

Comment: You can also try [Geocodio](http://geocod.io) which provides 2,500 free requests per day and $0.001 per additional request which is basically the cheapest solution. (Disclaimer: I work there)

Answer (score 2):

There are many providers that offer bulk and/or batch geocoding.  You can also purchase datasets, depending on your accuracy and coverage area requirements.  [As one example, Microsoft offers a solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx).  I can not vouch for its quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get on the horn to [SimpleGeo](http://simplegeo.com) and see what kind of deal could be put in play; they're a startup so probably hungry for volume business.

Otherwise, I'd probably start looking to the source rather than brokers like Google, e.g., TeleAtlas, but that's bound to be painful.

If you're daily numbers will be exponentially larger than 250K, e.g, 1.5e+16, you're bound to be repeating a lot of queries; find a way to clean them up/normalize them to increase cache hits and shove them into [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to keep the third-party queries down.

This is a helpful resource, stumbled across when looking for ways to get TIGER data which has to be free, but US only: http://www.vterrain.org/Culture/geocoding.html

Comment: Hi Yuri,

Thanks for the feedback.  I'll definitely check out SimpleGeo.  Also, caching is already in-place :)

Answer (score 1):

One comment on simplegeo , their api is simple and the you can query large number of records in a very short term . But their geo coding quality is not as good as Google or even Bing. I had many cases where I got the same coordinates for different set of addresses.
I'm looking for a solution my self and I'm testing the MapQuest api , seems like there is not rate limit (per say).